# Clear the events effect after the event is finished running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ahoy

I am using `ahoy_matey` gem . I am trying to record click event only when specific link is clicked.

So I have tried to do the following:

```
$("#lotto-bigyapan").on("click", function(){
ahoy.track("name", {element: "element"});
});
```

It works but the only problem here is, after I click on the specific link and everthing is working then if I click somewhere else then it ges recorded too. Is there a way to clear the effect once the click is stored in the db?

Comment: `$("#lotto-bigyapan").one('click', function() ...`

Comment: Hi @adeneo, your comment worked. Can you please turn it into answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the click event only fire once *per element*, you can use jQuery's `one()` method

```
$("#lotto-bigyapan").one('click', function(){
    ahoy.track("name", {element: "element"});
});
```